# How can I use Pandas to round inconsistent timestamps to five minute intervals and fill gaps?

Tags: python, pandas, time, weather

Input - one year of weather data at irregular intervals (~ 5 minutes)
Desired Output - one year of weather data at regular 5 min intervals

I'm trying to clean up a year of weather data, and would like to use this as an opportunity to explore the use of Python and Pandas. This is a process that needs to be repeated in the future, and automating it is highly preferable!

Sample of input

```
2/2/2015 8:03   43.5    
2/2/2015 8:08   43.4    0 
2/2/2015 8:13   43.3    0 
2/2/2015 8:18   43.2    7  
2/2/2015 8:28   43.1    9
2/2/2015 8:33   43      11 
2/2/2015 8:38   43      9 
2/2/2015 8:43   43      11
```

Sample of output

```
2/2/2015 8:00   43.5    
2/2/2015 8:05   43.4    0 
2/2/2015 8:10   43.3    0 
2/2/2015 8:15   43.2    7 
2/2/2015 8:20   N/A     N/A
2/2/2015 8:25   43.1    9
2/2/2015 8:30   43      11 
2/2/2015 8:35   43      9 
2/2/2015 8:40   43      11
```

Thank you for your help/suggestions!

Comment: What is the datatype of those first two columns?  Are they strings, datetimes, or something else?

Comment: All of the data is being pulled in from .csv or .xlsx files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with:

```
                        A   B
datetime                     
2015-02-02 08:03:00  43.5 NaN
2015-02-02 08:08:00  43.4   0
2015-02-02 08:13:00  43.3   0
2015-02-02 08:18:00  43.2   7
2015-02-02 08:28:00  43.1   9
2015-02-02 08:33:00  43.0  11
2015-02-02 08:38:00  43.0   9
2015-02-02 08:43:00  43.0  11
2015-02-02 09:00:00  43.1   9

DatetimeIndex: 8 entries, 2015-02-02 08:03:00 to 2015-02-02 08:43:00
Data columns (total 2 columns):
A    8 non-null float64
B    7 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2)
```

You can [`.resample()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) the `DateTimeIndex`:

```
df.resample('5Min')

                        A   B
datetime                     
2015-02-02 08:00:00  43.5 NaN
2015-02-02 08:05:00  43.4   0
2015-02-02 08:10:00  43.3   0
2015-02-02 08:15:00  43.2   7
2015-02-02 08:20:00   NaN NaN
2015-02-02 08:25:00  43.1   9
2015-02-02 08:30:00  43.0  11
2015-02-02 08:35:00  43.0   9
2015-02-02 08:40:00  43.0  11
2015-02-02 08:45:00   NaN NaN
2015-02-02 08:50:00   NaN NaN
2015-02-02 08:55:00   NaN NaN
2015-02-02 09:00:00  43.1   9
```

In case your `datetime` is actually of `type` `string`, you can first:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.datetime)
df.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan - That takes care of converting the type to a datetime, and rounding to 5 minute intervals. Any thoughts on checking for gaps inthe data, and inserting timestamps where gaps are present?

Comment: Worked like a charm - thanks @Stefan
    <import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
from pandas import Series, DataFrame, Panel
pd.options.display.max_rows =15

xlsx = pd.ExcelFile('C:\\Users\\IDL\\Desktop\\Weston_Data\\February.xlsx')
df = pd.read_excel(xlsx)
print ('Excel file successfully read!')

df = df.set_index('Time')
df.index = df.index.to_datetime()

clean5 = df.resample('5min')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('February_5min.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
clean5.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='February_5min')

writer.save()>